# Convert from iterator to the type of the variable. (C++11 Template)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator

I have template class which has a vector and default value in it

```
T _default;
vector<T> Vals;
```

I want to iterate over it and print the values based on type of default (either string/int/double).

so I wrote

```
if (typeid(int) == typeid(_default))
{
   for each(auto itr in Vals)
   {
     //logic to process each element in vector
     int temp;
     //temp = *itr; <------ how to convert from iterator to the value (value held in vector)
   }
}
else if (typeid(string) == typeid(_default))
{
   for each(auto itr in Vals)
   {         //logic to process each element in vector
     string temp;
     //temp = *itr; <------ how to convert from iterator to the value (value held in vector)


   }
}
else if (typeid(double) == typeid(_default))
{
   for each(auto itr in Vals)
   {
     //logic to process each element in vector
     double temp;
     //temp = *itr; <------ how to convert from iterator to the value (value held in vector)

   }
}
```

How to convert iterator to corresponding int/string/double. When I dereference it using `*itr` gives me  `error C2100: illegal indirection` error.

UPDATE: 
Sorry for update - but I actually want to compare value of a string say `string validateStr` to the values contained in `vector<T> Vals`. So I need to know the type of the values stored in `Vals` and then compare string by either doing (string to int)/(string to double)/(string(as is)) to each of the value in `Vals`. So basically this code will check if the `_default` value is actually is any of the values present in allowed `Vals`.

Comment: changed it to _default.

Comment: How do you want to print the values?

Comment: What language is this? `auto itr in Vals`

Comment: `itr` actually is not an iterator but an element of `Vals` there is no need to store it inside of temp. And only one of your code blocks can be compiles successfully so you need to use `constexpr if` or some templates. There is no need to use `typeid` when type is known at compile time.

Comment: `for each(auto itr in Vals)` doesn't look correct. Are you sure it isn't `for (auto itr : Vals)`?

Comment: `for each(auto itr in Vals)` is MS proposed for loop syntax that was supported in VS. The standard syntax would be `for(auto const & val: Vals)`.

Comment: If you just want to print them, why not just do this: `for (auto const& val : Val) { std::cout << val << std::endl; }` .. if the type has a stream operator overlaod, or is a basic type (like `int`), it will print. No need to check type.

Comment: @VTT , what do you mean by  `And only one of your code blocks can be compiles successfully so you need to use constexpr if or some templates.` Why only 1 block can be compiled. I dont quite understand it. :(

Comment: Assume that `Vals` holds ints, then code block treating `Vals` items as strings by calling `itr.c_str()` for example will be ill-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a range loop, the "iteration variable" has the type of the elements.
It's not an iterator.

You can't write the function like this since the entire function must be type-correct regardless of what `T` is.

What you can do is use an overloaded (or templated) function and pass the value to that:

```
void print(int i) { cout << "int " << i; }
void print(string s) { cout << "string " << s; }
// ...

for (auto v: Vals)
{
    print(v);
}
```

Comment: possible in newer C++ though, with `if constexpr`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing the point of a template. The idea is that you can create generalized code that handles all cases. So for example you say you want to:

> I want to iterate over it and print the values based on type of `_default` (either `string`/`int`/`double`)

In that case I'd say that you should create a `print` method in your class. For example:

```
void print() { for(const T& i : Vals) cout << i << ' '; }
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/GMwGx9)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the whole point of having a template is to avoid what you're trying to do  with your class.
Apart from the fact that you can achieve same results with specialized templates why not try `auto temp = *itr;` or better still type cast(*itr) but i'll still advise trying out template specialization.

A little example snippet for template specialization would be

```
template<typename T>
T add(T v1, T v2){
    return v1 + v2;
}

template <> double add(double v1, double v2){ return v1 + v2; }
template <> std::string add(std::string v1, std::string v2){ 
    return v1 + v2; 
}
template <> const char* add(const char* v1, const char* v2){ 
    return add(std::string(v1),std::string(v2)).c_str(); 
}

int main(){
    std::cout << add(1, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << add(2.6, 4.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << add("str", "ing") << std::endl;    
}
```